# Classes in razor engine template

Tags: c#, razor

Is it possible to create classes within a template? Something like...

```
@{
    public class MyClass {
        public MyClass() {
            Three = new List<string>();
        }

        public string One { get; set; }
        public int Two { get; set; }
        public List<string> Three { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Currently I get "Unable to compile template. Check the Errors list for details." when I try to do this. I would like to take XML content and use XmlSerializer to create an instance of MyClass within the template. I can't do the deserialization before hand and shove it into the model because the classes could vary depending on the template.

Comment: If it could wouldn't this completly bypass the whole idea of having models/views/controllers in the first place?

Comment: Can't you bring `MyClass` out into a separate file? OK, so that will make 2 files per template, but it will work.

Comment: Can you uncheck the "answer" and check the "Kirk Woll" answer instead as that is the correct answer.

Comment: @rene you and Vilx both right for general clean development concerns, but in my case I was needing to fill an online repro of a problem, so I had to put everything in a single view, including my Model class definition. It could also be useful for quick testing things. Kirk Woll gave the answer I was searching for.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible.   Use the `@functions` keyword:

```
@functions {
    public class MyClass {
        public MyClass() {
            Three = new List<string>();
        }

        public string One { get; set; }
        public int Two { get; set; }
        public List<string> Three { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether it is a good idea or not, is up for debate, but this does answer the question, so upvote from me. (Ans since I can only edit the views in my solution, this is what I need; despite the code smell)

Comment: This is perfect for the situation where you want to create intermediary transformation types but don't want to use anonymous types as you cannot pass those into razor helpers. 

Sadly, platforms like Umbraco do not work very well with code-heavy approaches. I wouldn't do this very often if your controllers are perfectly capable of performing all required transformations into a more concrete ViewModel.

Comment: upvote. on a larger project you don't do that usually but on normal small web matrix stuff, it would be smarter and easier. why all the smug bugs?

Comment: Upvoted and agree with the reservations/comments from @DarcyThomas and others.

Comment: Thanks. Really useful for testing things.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was searching for. Just using @{ ... } around class resulted in weird compilations errors ""must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial". In my case it's useful to fill an online repro of a problem, so I was needing to put everything in a single view, including my Model class definition. It could also be useful for quick testing things.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post my response from the [CodePlex Discussion](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/discussions/247706) here:

I'm not sure that is currently possible. When you use codeblocks (@{ }), you're actually writing code within a method, e.g. your above code would do something like:

```
public void Execute()
{
    this.Clear();
    public class MyClass {
        public MyClass() {
            Three = new List<string>();
        }

        public string One { get; set; }
        public int Two { get; set; }
        public List<string> Three { get; set;}
    }
}
```

...which of course, is not valid C#. The other problem you will face, is that to use xml serialisation/deserialisation, the type must be known, but if you are defining your type within the template itself, how could you deserialise it in the first place?

What you *could* do, is use a custom base template:

```
public class CustomTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
{
    public dynamic Instance { get; set; }

    public dynamic CreateInstance(string typeName)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

        // You'd to your deserialisation here, I'm going to
        // just cheat and return a new instance.
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Using a dynamic property and dynamic return type, we've defined a method that will let us create an instance (through activation or deserialisation, etc.) and call member access on it. To use that in a template, you could then do:

```
@{
  Instance = CreateInstance("ConsoleApplication1.MyClass, ConsoleApplication1");
  Instance.One = "Hello World";
}
<h1>@Instance.One</h1>
```

Where "MyClass" is a defined somewhere in my application. The important thing is, I'm creating an instance per template.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a specific ViewModel class, which could have a dynamic property (ExpandoObject) allowing you to populate it with any custom data structure as needed while still communicating strongly typed for whatever else your view might need.

This also keeps your view models separate from the views themselves, which is good practice (html and code don't mix too well where readability is a concern).