# The Name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context in a razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, viewdata

This is not a duplicate of [The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744174/the-name-viewdata-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) since that question asks about ASP.NET MVC, which is different from .NET Core!!!

I added the following C# code to my Razor page:

```
@{
public class MyUtility
{
    HttpContext httpContext;
    public MyUtility(HttpContext _httpContext)
    {
        httpContext = _httpContext;
    }

    Regex MobileCheck = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex MobileVersionCheck = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public bool IsMobileDeviceBrowser()
    {
        var u = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        if (u.Length < 4)
                return false;
        bool IsMobileBrowser = false;
        if (u.Length > 4 && (MobileCheck.IsMatch(u) || MobileVersionCheck.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4))))
            IsMobileBrowser = true;
        return IsMobileBrowser;
    }
}
}
```

and since then I keep getting errors for EVERY SINGLE CODE line besides the one I added to the razor page.
It's always this: `The name '' does not exist in the current context`
where '' is for example 'ViewData', 'Html' etc

How do I solve this problem?

I tried moving the `@using` tags but that didn't help at all.
I checked all of the code openings and closures and they're all balanced.

I am using .NET 6 version if that matters.

Comment: Maybe I'm supposed to add the class NOT into the Razor page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put classes into Razor pages (as a general recommendation, there might be cases where it is desired). However, it is possible by using the @functions keyword. The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129663/classes-in-razor-engine-template) elaborates on that topic.